# Can't locate where the '1' is coming from

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a quirky issue I'm trying to clear up on a web app that I've built. Everything is working fine with it except I have the numeral '1' showing up next to a checkbox control that I can't find the source of.  I've hit F12 and gone in to examine the resulting code for mark up and then traced back to the aspx page and there just isn't a '1' there for me to clear up that I can tell.

This is appearing in a panel that I have created for a multi row value change (shown here). You will see the numeral 1 after 'Ticket Closed:' and just before the checkbox control displayed:

[image]

And here is the aspx for the panel:

```
<%-- Column Edit Panel for modifying 'Ticket Closed' value --%>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="EditTicketClosedPnl" Visible="false">
        <asp:Table runat="server" CellPadding="10">
            <asp:TableRow HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <asp:TableCell>
                    Saving this edit will result in the value being populated to the column  and all rows for noted above. Cancel will abort the edit.
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table runat="server" CellPadding="5">
            <asp:TableRow VerticalAlign="Top">
                <asp:TableCell Width="150" HorizontalAlign="Right">
                    Ticket Closed:
                </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell Width="500" HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="TicketCldFocusTbx" TextAlign="Left" />
                </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right" >
                    (checked = Yes)
                </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Any idea's where for me to look would be greatly appreciated. I've been scratching my head about this rogue 1 for a couple days now.

Regards,
Kip...

Got it! Thanks for the feedback because while what I did wasn't in the suggestions I received, those ideas lead me directly to the following solution.

I added  >>> TicketCldFocusTbx.Text = null; <<<

To:

```
else if (ColumnSelectDDL.SelectedValue.ToString() == "TicketClosed")
    {
        EditTicketNumPnl.Visible = false;
        EditTicketClosedPnl.Visible = true;
        EditNotesPnl.Visible = false;
        EditExceptionIDPnl.Visible = false;
        EditIntExceptionIDPnl.Visible = false;
    }
```

Making it:

```
else if (ColumnSelectDDL.SelectedValue.ToString() == "TicketClosed")
    {
        EditTicketNumPnl.Visible = false;
        EditTicketClosedPnl.Visible = true;
        EditNotesPnl.Visible = false;
        EditExceptionIDPnl.Visible = false;
        EditIntExceptionIDPnl.Visible = false;
        TicketCldFocusTbx.Text = null;
    }
```

That resolved the issue.  I couldn't find anywhere in the code behind where the value was being set but since this was part of a GridView I'm thinking that I was getting the value from there.  I think what I will do is modify the edit box to ask if it is closed or not and then assign the value to the TicketCldFocusTbx just to keep it clean.

Thanks for the extra eyes!
Kip...

Comment: Search in your CodeBehind file 'TicketCldFocusTbx' and see if there you set the Text property to 1, I think TicketCldFocusTbx.Text = "1" shoudl be there somewhere!

Comment: Where does it appear in the output? That will give a clue as to where it is coming from... can you view source on the page and see where the 1 is in the page?

Comment: Just a guess, but if you are doing a sql query then you may be accidentally setting the Text property to the RowsAffected result.

Comment: Issue is resolve... Thanks to llouk and Crowcoder as you both pointed me in the direction of the issue.  I wasn't able to find where the assignment was taking place, but by setting TicketCldFocusTbx to null when I made the panel visible resolved the issue successful. 

Full details of what I did have been updated in the original post above.